# tmux loses context on attaching after reconnecting

Tags: ssh, tmux

I've been having an issue with `tmux` on one of my server machines.

When I attach to an existing tmux named session (using `tmux a -t<NUM>`) over a new SSH connection, it seems to lose local context.

This typically happens in my code's `build` directory.

For instance, running `make` returns:

```
make: getcwd: No such file or directory
```

Running `git status` returns:

```
fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory
```

However, all I need to do is run

```
cd `pwd`
```

and everything as expected again. Clearly, `pwd` seems to know where I am...

Do you know what's going wrong that my tmux session is losing this context?

Are there any commands that I can run to give you more information?

This is highly reproducible (happens every time I SSH in to this machine and attach to the same session).

Comment: When this happens and before you `cd`, what is the output of `echo $PWD`? `pwd -L`? `pwd -P`? (run them exactly in this order). Is there a discrepancy? Do all paths exist? Are there any symlinks involved? Is `pwd` command a shell builtin in whatever shell you use?

Comment: I have lost access to that environment and don't hit it anymore. Thanks for the tips, though.